# Purging Dead Nodes from SGE

Tags: sungridengine, qsub

My `qstat -g c` indicates that I have some dead nodes (formally '`cdsuE`'):

```
CLUSTER QUEUE                   CQLOAD   USED    RES  AVAIL  TOTAL aoACDS  cdsuE  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all.q                             0.11     18      0      9     37      0     10
```

Is there an easy way to purge or remove these nodes from the queue?

SGE is smart enough to not allocate work to them but they do clutter up various displays.

Answer (score 1):

I do it the hardway.

1. Kill the jobs "running" or stuck on dead nodes.
2. Run the qconf remove node pipeline

-

```
qconf -dattr hostgroup hostlist <nodealias> @allhosts'
qconf -purge queue slots all.q@<nodealias>
qconf -dconf <nodealias>
qconf -de <nodealias>
```

Comment: Is there a shortcut for removing the node from all hostlists and queues that it is a member of? (ie rather than having to hardcode `all.q`?

Comment: I am getting `Host object "node024" is still referenced in cluster queue "all.q".`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove from the queue then removing them from the queue
with:

`qconf -dattr queue hostlist <nodename> all.q`

or if they're incorporated via a hostgroup

`qconf -dattr hostgroup hostlist <nodename> <hostgroup>`

This does the minimum needed to get them out of the queue but makes it easy to add them back if you manage to resurect them later.

If there are any ghost jobs on the node then use qdel -f to get rid of them